# Remove duplicate words from text file input?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, text-files

I was playing around with a function that would take 3 arguments, the name of a text file, substring1 and substring2. It would search through the text file and return the words that contained both of the substrings:

```
def myfunction(filename, substring1, substring2)
    result = ""
    text=open(filename).read().split()
    for word in text:
        if substring1 in word and substring2 in word:
            result+=word+" "
    return result
```

This function works, but I would like to remove the duplicate results. E.g for my specific text file if substring1 was "at" and substring2 was "wh" it would return "what", however, because there are 3 "what"s in my text file, it returns all of them. I am looking for a way to not return duplicates, only unique words, I would also like to keep the ORDER, so does that count "sets" out?

I thought maybe doing something to "text" would work, somehow removing the duplicates before the loop.

Comment: a set would not preserve the order, though

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses **little memory** (use of an iterator over the file lines) and has a **good time complexity** (which matters when the list of returned words is large, like in the case where `substring1` is "a" and `substring2` is "e", for English):

```
import collections

def find_words(file_path, substring1, substring2)
    """Return a string with the words from the given file that contain both substrings."""
    matching_words = collections.OrderedDict()
    with open(file_path) as text_file:
        for line in text_file:
            for word in line.split():
                if substring1 in word and substring2 in word:
                    matching_words[word] = True
    return " ".join(matching_words)
```

The `OrderedDict` preserves the order in which the keys are first used, so this keeps the words in the order in which they are found. Since it is a mapping, there are no duplicate words. The good time complexity is obtained thanks to the fact that inserting a key in an `OrderedDict` is done in constant time (as opposed to linear time for the `if word in result_list` of many of the other solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Nah, all you need to do is make `result` a list instead of a string. Then, before adding each word, you can do `if word not in result:`. You can later convert the list into a space-separated string via `''.join(result)`.

This will preserve the order in which they are found, whereas a set won't.

Comment: Oh ok, i'll give that a go, I did try use result as a string without  "if word not in result" earlier, and the list ended up as the correct words, however they were separated letter by letter by commas?

Comment: @user3528330 it sounds like you used `extend` rather than `append`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this, given that you want to keep the order, is to make `results` a list and check each `word` isn't already in the list before you add it. Also, you should really use the context manager `with` to handle files, to ensure they get closed properly:

```
def myfunction(filename, substring1, substring2)
    result = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = f.read().split()
    for word in text:
        if substring1 in word and substring2 in word and word not in result:
            result.append(word)
    return " ".join(result)
```

Comment: Same comment as for zmo: this has a bad time complexity.

Comment: @EOL that is true, but on the other hand it is straightforward and readable and `n` may not be very large.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's an interesting point, but Python does offer us a quite straightforward solution thanks to its `OrderedDict`. As for "`n` may not be very large", we really don't know (that's certainly not the case if `substring1` is 'e' and `substring2` is 'a', in English). In any case, I don't think there is much reason to not choose the efficient solution (again, where efficient = good time complexity): it takes the exact same number of lines and reads almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the with statement to use the file's context manager. Using a list and testing for the presence of the string within the list will do the job for you:

```
def myfunction(filename, substring1, substring2)
    result = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for word in f.read().split():
            if substring1 in word and substring2 in word:
                 if not word in result:
                     result.append(word)
        return result
```

And consider returning a list instead of a string, as you can always convert the list into a string easily whenever you need it, doing:

```
r = myfunction(arg1, arg2, arg3)
print(",".join(r))
```

edit:

@EOL is perfectly right so here am I giving two more time efficient approach (but slightly less memory efficient):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def myfunction(filename, substring1, substring2)
    result = OrderedDict()
    with open(filename) as f:
        for word in f.read().split():
            if substring1 in word and substring2 in word:
                 result[word] = None # here we don't care about the stored value, only the key
        return result.values()
```

the `OrderedDict` is a dictionary which preserves the order of insertion. And a dictionary's keys is a special case of `set`, which share the property of having only unique values. So if a key is already in the dict, when inserted a second time, it'll be silently ignored. That operation happens way faster than looking up a value in a list.

Comment: `if not word in result` is not efficient (in terms of time complexity). A more appropriate structure is an `OrderedDict`, for instance, which has a much better membership testing time complexity.